# Spring handling bean colliision with library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here's the situation: I have a `RestTemplate` bean defined in my main application (Spring boot 2). This application uses a library that also defines a `RestTemplate` bean to handle requests. I want to keep the main application's `RestTemplate` definition for my code, **but I don't want the library to use my bean definition**, since it will create a weird behaviour.

Is there a way to do that without using `@Qualifier` everywhere? Perhaps something like scoping my bean to my code only?

Comment: `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`?

Comment: Then woudn't my code would use the library's definition instead of mine?

Comment: my bad, I've just read more carefully. can you may be create your bean instead of `RestTemplate` and use that everywhere? `class MyRestTemplate { private RestTemplate restTemplate; ...  }` and provide a method like `@Bean public MyRestTemplate(<yourRestTemplate>)` and use that everywhere?

Comment: If the library is a true spring boot starter you should be able to create whatever bean is requiring a resttemplate and provide its own unique rest template,  while still defining your own. Depending on the design you may also be able to just call a setter on the bean that you want to replace the RestTemplate